# Cloudformation Elasticache: "cannot be specified along with CacheSecurityGroupNames"

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, aws-cloudformation, amazon-elasticache

ERROR:

> Properties [AZMode, CacheSubnetGroupName, SecurityGroupIds, PreferredAvailabilityZones, SnapshotArns, SnapshotRetentionLimit, SnapshotWindow, Tags] cannot be specified along with CacheSecurityGroupNames, please update your template to the latest version

```
Type: AWS::ElastiCache::CacheCluster
    Properties:
      Engine: redis
      AZMode: single-az
      EngineVersion: 5.0.6
      CacheParameterGroupName: !Ref CacheParameterGroup
      ClusterName: !Sub ${SystemName}-${Env}-elasticache
      CacheNodeType: !Ref ElasticacheNodeType
      NumCacheNodes: "1"
      Port: 6379
      PreferredMaintenanceWindow: !Ref MaintenanceWindow
      PreferredAvailabilityZone: ap-northeast-1a
      SnapshotRetentionLimit: !Ref SnapshotRetentionLimit
      SnapshotWindow: !Ref SnapshotWindow
      CacheSubnetGroupName: !Ref CacheSubnetGroup
      CacheSecurityGroupNames:
        - Fn::ImportValue: DevElasticacheSG
```

Whats the reason for above error in cloudformation?

Answer (score 1):

[CacheSecurityGroupNames](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-elasticache-cache-cluster.html) can only be used when your cluster is not in VPC:

> Use this parameter **only when you are creating a cluster outside of an Amazon Virtual Private Cloud** (Amazon VPC).

My guess is that maybe you wanted to use [VpcSecurityGroupIds](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-elasticache-cache-cluster.html#cfn-elasticache-cachecluster-vpcsecuritygroupids) instead.